# Apostrophe on text boxes

Tags: php, html

I fetched an information from the database which I want to display on a textbox but it is always failing.

The value I get from the database:
`$text = "Keith's Club";`

`echo "<input type='text' value='$text' />";`

It should return `Keith's Club` inside the text box but what happens is that it only displays `Keith`

I tried

`<input type='text' value='".htmlspecialchars(stripslashes($cname))."' />;`

But it isn't working.

Answer (score 2):

You should make sure that you use the quotestyle and charset with `htmlentites()`, which the php page in your editor should be encoded the same like:

```
$text = "Keith's Club";
echo "<input type'text' value='".htmlentities($text, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8')."' />";
```

Again: Make sure your php page in your editor is correctly encoded.

Comment: More complicated than it probably needs to be, isn't it? If you use double quotes on your HTML attributes, you can ommit `ENT_QUOTES`. Also UTF-8 is the default encoding from PHP 5.4.0 onwards.

Answer (score 0):

Use [htmlentities](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php):

```
echo '<input type="text" value="'. htmlentities($text) .'" />';
```

or better yet:

```
$text = htmlentities("Keith's Club");
```